# Purchase events not recorded in Enhanced Ecommerce for Android app

Tags: android, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I've been working with an agency specialized in mobile development to install Enhanced Ecommerce with GTM on a mobile app. Screen view tracking and custom events are working fine, but we're struggling to get all data showing in Ecom reports.[See current Product List Performance Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qASxZ.png) (yes, not all data makes sense yet)

It seems the product checkout is tracked properly, but purchase events are flawed. FYI, both checkout + purchase data are sent with a custom event, on click of a button. Event reports show that the events themselves are collected OK.

Here are some of the data pushes (Android):

Clicks

```
{ecommerce=
 {click=
  {products=
   [{quantity=1, name= Beer, price=12.12, category=Beverages/Beer/Beer-Import, isNewPrice=No, brand=Miller Chill, id=00000_000000003410034805}], 
    actionField={list=Category Browsing}}}}
```

Add to cart

```
{ecommerce=
 {add=
  {products=
   [{quantity=1, name= Beer, price=12.12, category=Beverages/Beer/Beer-Import, isNewPrice=No, brand=Miller Chill, id=00000_000000003410034805}]}, 
   currencyCode=CAD}}
```

Checkout

```
{ecommerce=
 {checkout=
  {products=
   [{quantity=3, name= Beer, price=12.79, isNewPrice=No, brand=Miller Chill, id=00000_000000003410034805}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime A Rita Beer, price=16.99, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820019987}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime-A-Rita Beer, price=1.9899999999999998, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820000960}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime Beer, price=21.99, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820014990}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Premium 4.8% Can Beer, price=8.99, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bitburger, id=00000_000000002050700011}], 
     actionField={step=1}}}}
```

Purchase - fired on the same page as checkout (1 page checkout), but with a different event

```
{ecommerce=
 {purchase=
  {products=
   [{quantity=3, name= Beer, price=12.12, category=Temp, isNewPrice=No, brand=Miller Chill, id=00000_000000003410034805}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime A Rita Beer, price=12.12, category=Temp, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820019987}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime-A-Rita Beer, price=12.12, category=Temp, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820000960}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Lime Beer, price=12.12, category=Temp, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bud Light, id=00000_000000001820014990}, 
    {quantity=1, name=Premium 4.8% Can Beer, price=12.12, category=Temp, isNewPrice=No, brand=Bitburger, id=00000_000000002050700011}], 
     actionField={revenue=101.56, tax=0, id=f0deeb4a-7552-493a-a113-ea9ea356b6e8, affiliation=Mobile, shipping=0}}}}
```

Do you see anything that would prevent Google from recording a transaction? All tags are also set with "Enable Enhanced Ecomm" and "Use data layer = true".

Thank you so much,

Charles

Comment: Did you find the issue?

Comment: did you get the solution ??

Comment: I have the same issue. Has anyone managed to resolve this?

Comment: A possible workaround was described here: https://medium.com/@vadymov/how-i-get-free-advice-from-top-ctos-2972d27703b1

Answer (score 1):

There is an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35353973) with the Google Analytics data package, which is limited by 8192 bytes. Once crossed the transaction is dropped silently.

[Our solution](https://medium.com/@vadymov/how-i-get-free-advice-from-top-ctos-2972d27703b1) was to send minimal data (product SKUs, quantities and prices) while importing the metadata periodically into the Google Analytics dashboard via the API or manually.

Shout out to [Guy Korland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/593425/guy-korland) for pointing it out [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/g_korland/status/1157406429424300032).